# Borrar sesiones php, para que no haya 2 sesiones simultáneamente de un mismo usuario?

Tags: php, sesiones

Por más que busco por internet no encuentro la solución.
Tengo un proyecto hecho, con sesiones, en el que no quiero que haya sesiones simultáneas del mismo usuario, he conseguido hacerlo en un navegador, de forma que si hay una sesión iniciada en el mismo, me redirija al inicio.

Pero lo que quiero conseguir es que si voy a otro navegador e inicio sesión con la misma cuenta, me borre del servidor (carpeta tmp) el archivo de sesión creado desde el otro navegador justo antes de crear la nueva sesión, para que haya solo una. Me suena algo de usar unset pero no puedo perder mucho tiempo investigando porque lo necesito para mañana :(

Comment: lo que podrias hacer es en tu tabla de usuarios o donde valides el login crear un campo adicional que diga login donde 1 es si Y 0(cero) es no..

Comment: cuando el usuario esta logeado se pone 1 y si desea acceder de otro navegador verificas este campo y no dejas ingresar o haces lo que deseas

Comment: Es útil si no quiero dejarle ingresar hasta que cierre la sesión y ese campo se cambie a 0, el problema es que quiero dejarle ingresar y para ello necesito que se haya cerrado la anterior sesión, la haya cerrado él o no, y en este último caso, se destruya la anterior antes de crear la nueva. Por ejemplo, imagina este caso: me logueo desde una biblioteca, me descuido y me voy sin cerrar la sesión , cuando llego a casa ese ordenador de la biblioteca sigue encendido, y como no se ha cerrado esa primera sesión, no me deja entrar desde el ordenador de mi casa

Comment: Bueno, al final después de probar me funcionó el método de poner el 1 y el 0 que me dijiste arriba, muchas gracias! :D

Comment: es una solucion temporal... tambie podrias revisar esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727919/how-to-prevent-multiple-logins-in-php-website